# Setting message i18n dynamically in Grails

Tags: spring, grails, grails-2.0

I am trying to add some additional values into the i18n messageSource in Grails.

The default message.properties work fine but I need some additional values loaded from a remote resource (I know it is not good, but you know, managements... ).

I am trying to load these variables through the Boostrap.groovy
example:

```
def messageSource = new StaticMessageSource()
messageSource.addMessage("key1", new Locale("en"), "English Value")
messageSource.addMessage("key2", new Locale("de"), "Other Language Value")
```

When I try to access them in any GSP via the

```
<g:message code="key1" />
```

only the key is returned, as if the values where not set at all at the StaticMessageSource. Apparently I am not having much luck with the documentation.

There is nothing on the Grails website and almost nothing on the SpringFramework. 
Will appreciate any suggestions.

Anyother way to add the a set of messages to the messageSource Session!?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `messageSource` bean is declared in Grails with the `PluginAwareResourceBundleMessageSource` class. When I need more funcionality in this, I create a [grails plugin](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/plugins.html) and configure the context to load my class intead of the Grails one.

Something like:

*src/groovy/MyMessageSource.groovy*

```
class MyMessageSource extends PluginAwareResourceBundleMessageSource {
  String getMessage(String key, Object[] args, Locale locale) {
    String message
    //handle your custom keys
    if(key.contains('myCoolMessagePrefix') {
    } else {
      //or delegate to the default of Grails
      message = super.getMessage(key, args, locale)
    }

    return message
  }
}
```

*The plugin descriptor -> MyMessagesGrailsPlugin.groovy*

```
def doWithSpring = { 
  //here we change the bean definition to use the customized messagesource
  def beanconf = springConfig.getBeanConfig('messageSource')
  def beandef = beanconf ? beanconf.beanDefinition : springConfig.getBeanDefinition('messageSource')

  if (beandef) {
    beandef.beanClassName = MyMessageSource.class.name
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have solved a similar issue by following:

1. set the custom message codes in grailsApplication.config (you can
   set where-ever you want as long as you can get to it from your
   custom MessageSource)
2. extend the PluginAwareResourceBundleMessageSource
3. override the resolveCode and resolveCodeWithArguments, to check your
   custom source
4. use the "application" reference (its in the base class) to get to
   the config
5. redefine the message source in resources.groovy:

messageSource(MyMessageSource) { bean ->
    bean.autowire = "byName"    //-THIS IS IMPORTANT
    basenames = "WEB-INF/grails-app/i18n/messages"
}

Comment: Changing just the bean definition instead of declaring the messageSource will give you the option to let the Grails i18n plugin configure the bean. If you look at I18nGrailsPlugin, it does more than just basenames.

Comment: Helped a lot. Thank you!